# how to solve system of trigonometric function using sympy? Multiple values for x and y

Tags: python, algorithm, math, sympy

I have a set of trigonometric  equations

a variable `eq` is list of `sympy.core.relational.Equality`-

```
>>> print(eqn_to_solve)
Matrix([[cos(x)*cos(y)], [sin(x)*cos(y)], [sin(y)*cos(x)], [sin(x)*sin(y)]])
>>> print(ampls)
[0.41 0.57 0.57 0.41]
d_ampls = ImmutableMatrix(ampls)
>>>eq=[]
>>>for i in range(len(eqn_to_solve)):
.......eq.append(Eq(eqn_to_solve[i], dexp_ampls_sympy[i]))
>>>pprint(eq)
[cos(x)⋅cos(y) = 0.41, sin(x)⋅cos(y) = 0.57, sin(y)⋅cos(x) = 0.57, sin(x)⋅sin(y) = 0.41]
```

I get EmptySet when I use solvify as in

```
>>>from sympy.solvers.solveset import solvify
>>>sol = solvify(eq, x,y)
>>>print(sol)
EmptySet
```

What is the expected behavior when x,y can be solved for multiple values? How can solve for those multiple values of x, and y?

Comment: Where does `solvify` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 variables so giving 4 equations with Float numbers likely makes the system inconsistent, hence no solution. Try solving pairs at a time:

```py
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import subsets
>>> sol = set()
>>> for i in subsets(eq, 2):
    sol.update([Dict(i) for i in solve(i, dict=True)])
>>> len(sol)
24
```